# Create a single grafana alert for multi data-sources(multiple accounts) has similar content

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana, alert, monitoring

I want to create single lambda error alert in grafana for multiple AWS accounts, Please see below flow for more details.

> AWS Account 1 -> Datasource 1 (A) - {lambda-name} - {error-rate}
> AWS Account 2 -> Datasource 2 (B) - {lambda-name} - {error-rate}
>
> Alert --> {lambda-name} is failed with {error-rate} in Account - {Datasource-name(A or B .....)}

Please let me know how I can achieve this in grafana alerts.

> Grafana version - 9.3.2

I have tried the above alert, which is working for single individual account, but I am expecting it to create for multiple accounts together.

Comment: Here is [similar topic](https://community.grafana.com/t/alerting-from-multiple-sources/75043) on community.grafana.com.

Comment: It seem impossible to manage a big environment without this. Do I have to create one alert per environment (aka datasource in grafana)?